# Windows 8.1 BSOD DCP_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, crash, bsod

This BSOD happens every time I open certain programs. The whole computer goes into a freeze for about 2 minutes, then shows a blue screen. It gives me the error DCP_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION. I tried playing Counter Strike Source, BSOD. I tried playing osu!, BSOD. I tried opening PC Settings, BSOD. I tried reading the .dmp files but the default program to open it with (Visual Studio), and I got a BSOD. I tried installing Windows Debugger Tool, I got a BSOD. I don't know how to read the dump file to check what caused it, so I'm stuck in this weird state which all I can do is go on the internet, because I'm too scared of crashing my computer again.

Can anyone help me out? I tried updating my SSD drivers but it did not work.

Comment: share the crash dumps from C:\Windows\Minidump

Comment: Like I said, I'm not actually able to open it. It crashes.

Comment: The [DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj154556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) error occurs when Windows or a driver spends too much time trying to service an interrupt or DPC. This means it is almost certainly a driver or hardware issue. If you can post the minidump to a file hosting site someone might be able to analyse it for you. I would not be able to check until this evening though hopefully someone else would be able to help sooner if you post the file.

Comment: I never told you to install anything. copy the dmps to an external drive, go to a difference device and upload them.

Answer (score 0):

This bug tends to be caused by faulty driver and I experienced it a lot before Windows 8 went in the final version. Your SSD might be the cause, in this case the solution probably comes from updating its firmware. I did that on mine and it stopped the random BSoDs. Usually you have either tools that can work online (when booted up) or offline for patching your SSD, I would avoid using an online tool since your computer may crash during this so either do it from a different OS or use the offline CD (or USB stick).

You can also check this for reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj154556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Like I've said, I've already tried to update my drivers. Perhaps I did it wrong?

Comment: Where do I look for firmware updates?

Comment: Well for a start go to the manufacturer's website I guess

Comment: I don't know who my ssd is from. I don't even know if it's an SSD. It was included with my laptop, has storage of 25gb. http://i.imgur.com/xpzX2SF.png

Comment: Well that's the name just there. You just need to look up st1000lm024 hn-m101mbb in google

Comment: 15 seconds of google and I got this: http://files.hddguru.com/download/PC-3000-UDMA%20Support/SAMSUNG/M8/ please try to update and see if you get any result there